# OpenCV: Am I declaring matrix correctly?

Tags: c++, opencv, for-loop, matrix, type-conversion

I want to change:

```
int q[10] ;
double weight[10];

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) 
{
    q ++ ;
    weight[i] = 10;
}
```

into cv::Mat form, so I did it like this:

```
cv::Mat q = cv::Mat ( 1, 10, CV_8UC3 );
cv::Mat w = cv::Mat ( 1, 10, CV_8UC3 );    

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i ++ )
{
    uchar* p = q.ptr ( i );
    *p += 1; 
}
    weight.setTo ( 10 );
```

The code compiles without error, but since I don't have any reference to judge the result, I doubt there might be mistakes in my changes. Or am I doing everything right here? Thank you.

Comment: your original code doesn't make sense to me. what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to set all the values of "weight" into "10", and increase all the values of "q" by "1". This is a partial code of my c++ class on which I am working to change into OpenCV form. In my class there are plenty of such cases, so I need to take one of them as an example here.

Comment: did you just update the for loop index? also maybe you wanna replace `w` with `weight`?

Comment: yes, I updated it, my mistake while writing it here. thank you for pointing out.

Comment: and why are you increasing the value of a pointer? did you mean `q[i]++` by any chance?

Comment: yes I am, and I don't know I am doing it correctly, so that is why I asked for your help. It is wrong, right?

Comment: no I meant in the first part of the code. there's nothing wrong with asking for help, I'm just trying to be sure that your original code is what you actually meant.

Comment: no, I said "it is wrong", I meant my code is wrong. I am not very familiar with changes like these. so I need others like you to help me find my errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int q[10]` will be changed to `cv::Mat q = cv::Mat(1,10,CV_32SC1);`

`double w[10]` will be changed to `cv::Mat w = cv::Mat(1,10,CV_64FC1);`.

You can access the raw pointers as:

`int* qPtr = q.ptr<int>();`

`double* wPtr = w.ptr<double>();`

Comment: then how to access the single values? I mean for instance I want to set q[8] = 5, then can I just do "qPtr = 5"? I don't think so, could you help? thank you.

Comment: come on... thats simple C. You just do `qPtr[8] = 5;`

Comment: aha...sorry, I was trying to think it in complicated manner :D thank you so much.